# Create random resource name in Terraform

Tags: random, azure-storage, terraform

I'm using Terraform to create stuff in Azure,

In ARM I used to use uniqueString() to generate storage account names,

So is it possible to generate random name for storage account using Terraform?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several random resources you can use in Terraform

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/random/index.html

Resources

```
random_id
random_pet
random_shuffle
random_string
```

Use `random_id` as a sample, and the official codes in [resource azurerm_storage_account](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_account.html)

You can define the resource `azurerm_storage_account` name easily.

```
resource "random_id" "storage_account" {
  byte_length = 8
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "testsa" {
  name                = "tfsta${lower(random_id.storage_account.hex)}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.testrg.name}"

  location     = "westus"
  account_type = "Standard_GRS"

  tags {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help! I've updated config following your advice - http://prntscr.com/gpf17c but it fails - http://prntscr.com/gpf1ue any ideas why it fails?(

Comment: I updated the code, and add `lower()` function around the random id and remove "-" from the name, could you try again?

Comment: `lower()` and using `.hex` attribute is important in this case to conform with the naming restrictions of storage account.